# How to monitor for a system color change in a WinUI 3 application

Tags: winui-3

If I have a WinUI 3 application that is executing, and I change the Color setting from Light to Dark in the Settings/Personalization/Colors dialog, how can I detect this change in the WinUI 3 application?

Comment: It works automatically for me (little app on a default project). Then again, I'm on Windows 11. 
Maybe check if default projects or samples do it on your system!?

Answer (score 1):

After rephrasing my question to UWP from WinUI 3, a satisfactory answer resulted. The UISettings class provides the solution.

```
UISettings uiSettings = new UISettings();

uiSettings.ColorValuesChanged += ColorValuesChanged;

private void ColorValuesChanged(UISettings sender, object args)
{
  var accentColor = sender.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Accent);

  var backgroundColor = sender.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Background);
}
```

Thanks to Martin Zikmund for this solution:
https://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/01/observing-system-color-changes-in-uwp-apps/